# C++: Scheduling logic

Tags: c++, scheduling

I have a task where i will receive the schedules like below( Example ):

3,5,6 ( represents days of a week )

9:30 - 13:45, 15:12 - 18:75 ( Time Slots )

These days and slots are applicable for an year or more.

We are currently storing them in a config file. So, i have to start a task based upon these schedules i.e., on 3rd day of week at 9:30 i have to start the task and suspend it once it reaches 13:45.

We are using C++ for our prod. We cant use boost for now.

Q: What do you suggest is the best way to achieve this? I have implemented in a way where basically split( must ) and then comparing with system date which has lead to a cumbersome code and buggy to some extent.

I believe people would have faced similar issues earlier. Iam concentrating more on best approach to cover all boundary cases like end of day, start,leap,non leap. Any best and efficient approach do you people suggest with your experience?

Thanks~
Santhosh

Comment: What system (Windows, *NIX, etc)? Is it kind of Windows's task scheduler?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is this about the date arithmetic (there are a bunch of POSIX functions for this in `time.h`)? The file format? Are you also wondering how each "task" should be started/suspended? Narrowing it down will yield better answers.

Comment: Its a linux machine. Iam looking at how best to do this. Are there any links with similar usages\examples ? How to suspend the task when the time reached, how do we verify when the end time reached etc? Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

I did my own petty\pretty scheduller to go around this. So far so good working with this!!